# Internal error memory limit exceeded in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

I was using svn as repository. Recently I was asked to move to Git. I am using EGit plugin for eclipse. But whenever I try to do Team -> Synchronize Workspace , I am facing below error

An internal error occurred: Synchronizing Git. GC limit exceeded.

I googled it

https://www.simplified.guide/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

and tried increasing the heap size in eclipse.ini file (-Xms512m -Xmx1024m) but still I am facing the same issue, whenever I do git synchronize. sometime I also get

An internal error occurred: Synchronizing Git. Java Heap Size.

I tried increasing both the size till 2048 but still not yet resolved. Have anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use Team -> Synchronize Workspace anymore. In the EGit view, select your branch, and EGit will automatically update your package/project view. To "synchronize" using Git you need to push and pull changes to the remote repo.

You should also consider not using EGit, but rather a separate Git client, which is much more feature rich and functional (based on personal experience) than EGit. I've had great luck with SourceTree (Mac OSX) and TortoiseGit (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

This bug was resolved on February 2nd, you have to install EGit from the nightly releases site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: I was getting a heap overflow error on Juno but updating to [Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) seemed to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problems here. Having a pretty large project (7GB, I already stripped out some 4GB).  Going out of heap, and Eclipse suggest closing down.

Using the command line to do "git push" manually works better. At least I see some progress info and upload speeds.

I now see this

```
Counting objects: 810, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (688/688), done.
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 200.19 MiB/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (809/809), 5.87 GiB | 25.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 809 (delta 186), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Not sure, i don't see my files on github yet...